# IntelliJ gives error in editor on generated code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

I have a project in IntelliJ with 2 annotation processors: Lombok, and another, simple processor.

- When compiling with Gradle, either inside or outside IntelliJ, everything works fine.
- When running with the default IntelliJ settings, Lombok works but the other processor does not
- When I check the `Enable annotation processing` box under Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation processors, the second processor is executed, but compilation fails with an error where the generated code is used
- When I also change the sources directory to `.` (from `generated` which is the default), the IntelliJ build succeeds, and it can run my tests. However, the editor window still gives an error where the generated code is used. Autocompletion doesn't work either.
- If I add the second processor's FQN under Annotation Processors, the errors go away, but Lombok no longer works (causing even more errors). Also adding Lombok there doesn't help.

How do I get *all* of IntelliJ to play nice with the annotation processors?

I'm using IntelliJ 15.0.5, Lombok 1.16.8, IntelliJ Lombok plugin 0.10.15, Gradle 2.12, OpenJDK 1.8.0_66, Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ's in-editor code highlighting does not rely on a Java compiler and therefore does not support annotation processing. You can add support for your own annotation processor by writing a plugin that would tell IntelliJ about the methods generated by your annotation processor; this is what the IntelliJ Lombok plugin does.

Comment: but: `If I add the second processor's FQN under Annotation Processors, the errors go away`. Why?